# Alert hello world not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have created a webservice to alert hello world using javacript. But no results come. Even no error. I couldnot figure out where I do the mistake. I just host the wsdl in locally. What have I missed?

Here is my code

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/NetWebsite/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/NetWebsite/js/script.js" ></script>

 <script language="JavaScript">
     var iCallID;
     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService(http://localhost:5431/WebSite1/WebService.asmx?WSDL,"HelloWorldService");
      service.HelloWorldService.callService("HellowWorld");
     }
     function ShowResult(){   
      alert(event.result.value);

     }

    </script>

    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
 <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" 
    style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)" onresult="ShowResult()"> 


    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">

        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that service is actually being called on page load?

Comment: I want to call the service on button click. I did like this 
  <button onclick="ShowResult()">Get Age</button>
Still not working

Answer (score 1):

First, you forgot quotes in service address. It should be:

```
service.useService("http://localhost:5431/WebSite1/WebService.asmx?WSDL","HelloWorldService");
```

Second, you cannot initialize service and get result in the same DOM element.
Initialize in BODY and then get result in a DIV, for example.
Here you have some more details:
http://www.webreference.com/js/column99/7.html